# MSDTC Port 135 open bi-directionally

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

I have two servers, a web application server and an SQL Server database running on its own server.

I have a firewall between these two servers.

Do I have to open port 135 on both the SQL Server and the Web Application Server.

Does the SQL Server open its own connection to the Web Application Server on port 135 or any other port?

Do I have to in component services point the Web Application Server MSDTC at the SQL Database Server?

If the firewall is completely open, the settings in component services set to allow remote connections, remote administration etc is there any other settings that need to be changed in order to allow remote connections to the SQL Server MSDTC?

Answer (score 0):

I ran wireshark on this and found out the answers to my questions

1. yes you have to open 135 on both sql server and application server
2. No you don't have to use a remote transaction co-ordinator, you can use the local one
3. Yes if there is no firewall and all the local DTC settings in component services are set to allow incoming and outgoing traffic then there is no obstacle to the DTC working across multiple servers.